# What's behind the wall above fireplace

Tags: fireplace

What can I expect to find if I open up the wall above the fireplace (behind the T.V.)? Brick, wood studs, etc..

This is an exterior wall.

Thanks[image]

[image]

Comment: How far does the chimney stick out of the outside wall?

Comment: 16" from the outside wall.

Comment: How thick is the chimney above the roofline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have studs and drywall/plaster like the rest of the wall and a cutout where the fireplace is mounted with the chimney going up the outer wall. The brick and mantel probably go back to the unfinished wall.